# How to show different Frame per second of video in two window in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am using opencv to show frames from camera. I want to show that frames in to two separation windows. I want show real frame from camera into first window (show frames after every 30 mili-seconds) and show the frames in second window with some delay (that means it will show frames after every 1 seconds). Is it possible to do that task. I tried to do it with my code but it is does not work well. Please give me one solution to do that task using opencv and visual studio 2012. Thanks in advance

This is my code

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "exit" << endl;
    return -1;
}
namedWindow("Window 1", 1);
namedWindow("Window 2", 2);
long count = 0;
Mat face_algin;
while (true)
{
    Mat frame;
    Mat original;
    cap >> frame;
    if (!frame.empty()){
        original = frame.clone();           
        cv::imshow("Window 1", original);
        }
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;// Delay 30ms for first window
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could write the loop to display frames in a single function with the video file name as the argument and call them simultaneously by multi-threading.

The pseudo code would look like,

```
void* play_video(void* frame_rate)
{
    // play at specified frame rate
}
main()
{
    create_thread(thread1, play_video, normal_frame_rate);
    create_thread(thread2, play_video, delayed_frame_rate);
    join_thread(thread1);
    join_thread(thread2);
}
```

Comment: Please consider giving examples